# How to put ajax response inside related li element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax request on page loading, which will retrieve data for every li element by picking href link inside those li using jquery each() method to making dynamic url for ajax request for every li.

However, i have retrieve data for every li in ajax response but the problem is that all response is added to every li element not for related li.

How can i filter data for related li only ?

Here below is my code for making Ajax request :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.asd li a.sub-cat-name').each(function() {
        var urln = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: urln,
            success: function(data) {
                var res = $(data).find('.CategoryDescription').html();
                /*$('ul.asd li div.allprdct').each(function()
                {
                $(this).before('<div class="desc"> '+ res +' </div>');

                });*/
                $('ul.asd li div.allprdct').before('<div class="desc">' + res + '</div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the url for output page:-

http://www.development-rerack.mybigcommerce.com/cargo-boxes-baskets/

store preview code is: l5wv7x0rj2

This is a parent category page which is listing all sub categories in li. 
Now, on loading at this page i am making ajax request to these all subcategories page to retrieve category description of all subcategories by passing a dynamic url to ajax using jquery loop.

I can get description of all sub categories in ajax response but could't filter ajax response to display description to each individual related subcategory li.

Right now description of all subcategories is added to all li collectively     not for related li.

Please help to fix this problem.

Thanks and regards

Comment: could you please print the data content

Comment: This is the url for output page:-

http://www.development-rerack.mybigcommerce.com/cargo-boxes-baskets/

store preview code is: l5wv7x0rj2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you transform a few things about your method. Firstly, change your selector to only target the `li`s, not the `a` elements inside.

```
$('ul.asd li').each(function() {
```

Then, save the reference to each li, as a variable inside the function.

```
var li = $(this);
```

After which you can get the url like so.

```
var urln= li.find('.sub-cat-name');
```

Then finally, where you append the new data from the AJAX call, append it to the li variable. Each AJAX call will target it's own `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` to refer to the list item in each loop:

```
$('ul.asd li a.sub-cat-name').each(function() {
    var urln = $(this).attr("href"),
        $list = $(this).parent(); // <---- get the target list item here
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: urln,
        success: function(data) {
            var res = $(data).find('.CategoryDescription').html();
            $list.find("div.allprdct").before('<div class="desc">' + res + '</div>'); // <---add here.
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: I tried this but response is appended to last li , and response is not filtered to related li. I mean, response contains all li related data and append all data to li not for particular li.